# How is the function println not pure? (Clojure)

Tags: function, clojure, println

It always returns **nil**.

Doesn't that mean it's pure?

Does **println** cause any side effects??

Comment: Yes, it causes printing, which is a side effect.  So it's not pure.

Comment: Any function that does anything besides returning the value is not pure.

Comment: Any function that returns nil (or its synonyms in other languages like null, void, None, etc) is either impure or pointless, and not just in clojure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Side effects can be roughly defined as "*modifying any state not contained within the function itself*". This includes writing to disk or making some sort of external API call, etc. Since `println` writes to `STDOUT`, it is altering the state of the stdout. Therefore it has a side effect.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify here, no, reading/writing to/from memory does not count as a side effect.

Answer (score 4):

> It always returns **nil**.
>
> Doesn't that mean it's pure?

It only means it's pure if it doesn't have side-effects.

> Does **println** cause any side effects??

Yes, it prints.

If it didn't have a side-effect, it would be pretty boring since it also doesn't return anything sensible.

I prefer the term *referential transparency* to *purity*. An expression or a function is referentially transparent if you can replace it with its value (or vice versa) without changing the meaning of the program. This means that `println` is referantially transparent **IFF** I can replace any occurrence of `println` with `nil` or any occurrence of `nil` with `println` without changing the meaning of the program. Obviously, you can't do that, ergo, `println` is not referentially transparent / pure.